# Progress 4GL - week number of year

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm converting a date to its week number, but I get an error. Can you help me?

This is my code

```
function WeekNumber returns integer ( OrderRel.ReqDate as date ):

define var vDay as integer no-undo.

vDay = OrderRel.ReqDate - date( 1, 1, YEAR( OrderRel.ReqDate ) ) + 1.

return integer( truncate( vDay / 7, 0 ) ) + ( if vDay mod 7 <> 0 then 1 else 0 ).   

end function.
```

Comment: Please post the error message. Also, I notice that you are not using "." as your line ending character. You should use "." at then end of every statement.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a table-field as input to your function? You should change it into a local variable instead and then call it using the record:

```
FUNCTION WeekNumber RETURNS INTEGER ( INPUT pdaDate as DATE ):

    DEFINE VAR vDay AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

    vDay = pdaDate - DATE( 1, 1, YEAR( pdaDate ) ) + 1  .

    RETURN INTEGER( TRUNCATE( vDay / 7, 0 ) ) + ( IF vDay MOD 7 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) .

END FUNCTION.

MESSAGE WeekNumber( OrderRel.ReqDate ) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

This makes the function compile and run!

Another thing is that depending on what kind of week numbers you are calculating it might be wrong.

```
MESSAGE WeekNumber( DATE("2016-09-02") ) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

[image]

This is perhaps correct in your system, but at least not in Sweden that's utilising week numbering by the ISO8601 standard. By those standards September the 2nd 2016 is week 35...

[Week numbering on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering)

[ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week)